# Receiving Error while uploading multiple images

Tags: php, image, uploading

I'm getting this error while uploading multiple images kindly brief me how to remove this error.

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 25387890 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: you can fix by php.ini or .htaccess. or i suggest you to contact your service provider

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the limit on your post,

in `.htaccess`

```
php_value post_max_size 25M
```

You can also do the same in `php.ini` file.

After setting, restart your apache

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: First of all, this is comment. Secondly, this is what Mr. Niranjan Answered.

Comment: Hello, yes somehow the same. But if the post_max_size is already equal to the memory_limit you need to adjust the memory_limit. But you can accept Niranjan's answer than mine. Thank you.